# Trying to manage undefined value fetched from API - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fetching an id from one api and using that as a variable to fetch from another api. Unfortunately I can't be sure that I always get an ID from the first fetch so I need to gracefully assign a static ID or handle the error in some other way (preferably not doing a return for that function at all).

This is how my code looks right now, any ideas?:

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout.js";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";
import Error from "next/error";
import PageWrapper from "../components/PageWrapper.js";
import Menu from "../components/Menu.js";
import { Config } from "../config.js";

class Tjanster extends Component {

    static async getInitialProps(context) {
        const { slug, apiRoute } = context.query;

        const tjansterRes = await fetch(
            `${Config.apiUrl}/wp-json/postlight/v1/${apiRoute}?slug=${slug}`
        );
        const tjanster = await tjansterRes.json();

        const personId = tjanster.acf.person[0].ID;
        const personRes = await fetch(
            `${Config.apiUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/person/${personId}`
        );
        const person = await personRes.json();

        return { tjanster, person };
    }

    render() {

        if (!this.props.tjanster.title) return <Error statusCode={404} />;

        return (
            <Layout>
                <Menu menu={this.props.headerMenu} />

                <div className="single">

                    {this.props.person.title.rendered}

                    {this.props.tjanster.title.rendered}

                </div>

            </Layout>
        );
    }
}

export default PageWrapper(Tjanster);
```

I though about solving it somehow like this, but I only get personId is not defined:

```
static async getInitialProps(context) {
    const { slug, apiRoute } = context.query;

    const tjansterRes = await fetch(
        `${Config.apiUrl}/wp-json/postlight/v1/${apiRoute}?slug=${slug}`
    );
    const tjanster = await tjansterRes.json();

    if (tjanster.acf.person[0] === undefined) {
        const personId = 64;
    } else {
        const personId = tjanster.acf.person[0].ID; 
    }
    const personRes = await fetch(
        `${Config.apiUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/person/${personId}`
    );
    const person = await personRes.json();

    return { tjanster, person };
}
```

Preferably I would like it to not return "person" if the value is undefined, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: `const` has block scope, so `personId` will be undefined after your if/else. Try `let personId;` before the if/else and assign a value to that instead. It's probably best if you do this in `componentDidMount` instead, and set default data in your state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be absolutely sure that you are receiving a value, and you are receiving a correct value, you will have to validate the property of the object by validating every property like this:

```
let tjanster = await tjansterRes.json();

let personId = 64; // or whatever constant you want
if(typeof tjanster !== 'undefined'
  && tjanster.hasOwnProperty('acf')
  && tjanster.acf.hasOwnProperty('person')
  && tjanster.acf.person.length > 0
  && tjanster.acf.person[0].hasOwnProperty('ID')
  && !isNaN(tjanster.acf.person[0].ID)){
    personId = tjanster.acf.person[0].ID;
}
```

Then you could validate if the value is different than your constant:

```
if(personId === 64){
  return; // prevent call to your api
}

let personRes = await fetch(
    `${Config.apiUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/person/${personId}`
);
let person = await personRes.json();

return { tjanster, person };
```

The problem on doing this:

```
if (tjanster.acf.person[0] === undefined) {
    let personId = 64;
} else {
    let personId = tjanster.acf.person[0].ID; 
}
```

Is that if `tjanster.acf` is undefined, then you will get an exception that is not being handled because you will be calling the property `person` from an undefined object. The same happens if `tjanster.acf.person` is undefined, then `tjanster.acf.person[0]` throws an exception.

Comment: Hmmm, I added `return {tjanster};` so that it at least returns tjanster but not person. Also added `const` before `personId = tjanster.acf.person[0];` but unfortunately It wont work... I get "Cannot read property 'acf' of undefined" so I'm not sure but it seems like it does not return anything at all :/

Comment: @Triphys sorry, my bad. I modified my answer because I forgot to change all the `const` to `let`. Try it now and let me know.

Comment: Perfect! It solved my problem :) Thank you very much! Also added .ID in the personId so that it gets added.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a short circuit or making a function to handle the id

for example, with short circuit:

```
${Config.apiUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/person/${personId || "STATIC_ID"}`
```

or create a function so you can call it inside the string interpolation

```
${Config.apiUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/person/${handleId(personId)}`
```